# how to solve this error java.util.ConcurrentModificationException . i was writing a program to show occurence of letters using thread

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package thread;

import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
//concurrent modification error because of modifying map concurrently 

 class occurence extends Thread {
    String s;
    //HashMap
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map;
    occurence(String s,HashMap<Character,Integer> map){
        this.s=s;
        this.map=map;
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
           
            if(map.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
                map.put(s.charAt(i),map.get(s.charAt(i))+1);
            }else{
                map.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        HashMap<Character,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            String s=sc.next();
            occurence o= new occurence(s,map);
            o.start();
        }
        for(Entry<Character,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+entry.getValue());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

[image]

how to solve this error java.util.ConcurrentModificationException . i was writing a program to show occurence of letters using thread .i was expecting output as it would print character followed by their occurrences. [image]

Comment: You can solve that excpetion simply by using a `ConcurrentHashMap`. *But that doesn't make your code thread safe*. Think about what happens if two threads call `map.get()` with the same key, increment the value the received, and then update it. Look at the `Map.compute` method to do this safely.

Comment: That means that while one thread is modifying/entering an entry to hashmap, another thread is modifying the same hashmap. Hashmap is NOT thread safe

Comment: Also, cant you take a screenshot instead of a photo of the screen?

Comment: Please do not upload images of text, whether for code, error messages, example input, expected output, or actual output. Instead, copy-and-paste the text into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

Once you start the processing in a thread, you should wait for it to complete. You can do this by calling the `join()` method on the thread.

But, this will cause the main thread to wait for the result before processing the next user-inputted string.

Next, you aren't handling multiple inputs from the user. This again depends on how you want to handle the threads.

1. If you want to create one thread for each input and okay to wait till the processing is done, you can print the result (map contents) after the thread has completed its work.
2. If you don't want to be blocked by the thread, then you have to start the threads, store the reference to them in a list and then wait for their completion at the end. You also have to create one map instance for each thread and store them as well so that you can print all of them at the end.

   - (As a more advanced approach) You can also use an `ExecutorService` to submit multiple tasks and wait for their completion. If you are interested, you can search about this.

To keep it simple, assuming you want to create a thread for processing and will wait for it to complete before moving to process the next input, you can change your code as,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    String s = sc.next();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Occurrence o = new Occurrence(s, map);
    o.start();
    o.join();

    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

You can notice several modifications:

1. I've used a `LinkedHashMap` to maintain the insertion order (as per your requirement). Also, creating one new map for each input processing.
2. Calling `o.join()` to wait for the thread to complete.
3. Moved the *for* loop to print the map contents inside the first *for* loop. When you have a *char* `+` *int*, it will convert the character to an integer and perform numeric addition. To avoid it, I've concatenated the character with an empty string. Or you can call `.toString()` on the Character instance as well.
4. Renamed the `occurence` class as `Occurrence` to follow Java's naming convention.

Finally, don't close the `Scanner` backed up by `System.in`.